# Когда браузер начинает парсить CSS?

Tags: css, браузер

Не могу найти никак однозначной информации, когда начинается браузером парсинг CSS для построения CSSом. Где-то пишут, что во время построения DOM, мол это два параллельных процесса. Где-то, что после полного построения DOM.

Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Начинает парсить сразу же когда встречает CSS в коде. При этом построение DOM останавливается.